# Recarregar DataGridView em C#

Tags: c#, .net, lista, datagridview

Estou criando um evento de um botao na qual ele cria um objeto Produto e adiciona em uma lista de Produtos e utilizando esta lista para preencher o DataSource de um dataGridView, porem o DataGridView continua sempre aparecendo um unico produto.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Produto produto = new Produto();

      venda.ItensVenda.Add(produto);

      dataGridView1.DataSource = venda.ItensVenda;

      dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A referência ao `datasource` ainda continua, mesmo após outro click.
Force a limpeza para uma atualização bem sucedida.

Acrescente a linha:

> `dataGridView1.DataSource = "";`

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Produto produto = new Produto();

      venda.ItensVenda.Add(produto);

      dataGridView1.DataSource = "";
      dataGridView1.DataSource = venda.ItensVenda;

      dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

---

### Complementação de Resposta

Outra forma de fazer, é utilizar o [`BindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) na criação do seu objeto `ItensVenda`. Desta forma, os dados serão vinculados automaticamente dispensando o `DataSource = ""`.